# How to turn on the automatic prompt function of PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, intellisense, interactive, psreadline

I don't know what happened when I was using `PowerShell`.My `PowerShell` suddenly had an automatic completion function, but I don't know how I opened it.

I suspect this is running a certain command or using a shortcut key.
But before running this feature, I only used `ls` and `dir`.

My version of `PowerShell` is 7.3.5.

[image]

Comment: Look at the prompt on each line.  When you are running PS the line starts with PS.  You are running Flutter and NPM which are applications and ls will not work in Flutter and NPM

Comment: @jdweng I didn't run NPM or Flutter, I was just demonstrating its automatic prompt function.

Comment: Prompting in PS stops if you are in an application (NPM, Flutter) or if your PS command is not complete like you do not have match single quotes or brackets.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the *Predictive IntelliSense* feature [introduced in v2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-psreadline-2-1-with-predictive-intellisense/) of the [`PSReadLine` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline), which ships with recent versions of [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (but you're always free to install the latest version via `Install-Module PSReadLine -Scope CurrentUser`, for instance).

To disable this feature, place the following [`Set-PSReadLineOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineOption) in your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles):

```bash
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource None
```